# Ubuntu, mail servers and MX records

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, mx-record, pop3

**Some background:** 
I have set up an Ubuntu cloud server on Rackspace where I host two domains, say, www.domain1.co.uk and www.domain2.co.uk.

Both domains are hosted on the same cloud server. I purchased the domains from 123-reg and redirected the name servers to my rackspace servers and it all works fine.

**Requirement:**
I need to enable domain specific mail accounts for both domains so I can send and receive mail from info@domain1.co.uk and info@domain2.co.uk.

I've looked into setting up a mail server on the domain servers. But I really would like to keep the server free. What would be the best/most cost effect/simplest options for achieving the requirements and how would I go about setting it up?

Sorry if this is too open a question.

Thanks for your help!

ELA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest, cheapest: Use Google Apps for Domains to host the mail for the domains.  When you setup the domains on Google Apps, they'll give you the necesssary MX records you'll need to put into the DNS zone for the domains to make it all work.  As long as you don't change the `A` records for the domains, the web hosting will be unaffected.

Comment: Thanks! So helpful! - I should ask questions more often :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, absolutely agree. If it under 10 mailboxes per domain Google Apps is the way to go. You need the zone editor for your domain to set appropriate CNAMEs and MX records. If it is something you could do with the tools provided by rackspace, then use it, if not consider zoneedit.com. Its free for 5 domains I believe.